# Add padding to display

Tags: windows-xp, display, resolution, lcd

I know this one is a bit weird.

I need to scale down the display on my monitor like the example below:

[image]

Normally, this could be done with some adjustments in monitor's OSD, but there is no OSD on my LCD monitor.

Is it even possible by software?

**Edit:**
Graphic Card: **Intel  G33/G31 express Chipset family**

It would be good if it's permament but it's not needed.

I can change my operating system but currently i use Windows XP.

Comment: You need to give much more information:  what hardware (video chipset and monitor) do you have?  What operating system are you using?  Should this be a permanent change, or do you want to do it temporarily for specific circumstances?

Comment: Please tell us why you need to do this, then we may be able to offer other advice.

Comment: We've got a kiosk prepared. But they've cut the piece covering the LCD wrong, and it now blocks the display area. We will sell this kiosk and we don't know what applications will run on it.

Answer (score 1):

See if this article applies to your card:
[Intel® Clear Video Technology controls questions and answers](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-029863.htm).

The section titled `Can I change the aspect ratio for my widescreen display using this technology?` says:

> The Video Scaling tab (see Figures 4 &
>   5, for newer drivers Figures 4a)
>   allows you to enable and configure
>   various settings of Non-Linear
>   Anamorphic Scaling (NLAS). NLAS scales
>   content with 4:3 aspect ratio to
>   widescreen displays with 16:9 aspect
>   ratio while minimizing the loss of
>   image quality.

It seems from the image below that the driver does support cropping of the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have an Nvidia card on my laptop. I have to change the "flat panel scaling".

Comment: I have an Intel card, unfortunately it has limited amount of settings.